# How do I export a YouTube playlist?

Tags: youtube, export, youtube-playlist

How do I export a YouTube playlist (video names) to Excel or a document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the playlist is public you can get atom feed of it with an http request like.

- https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?playlist_id=ID

Where the ID is replaced with an actual ID like this.

- https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?playlist_id=PL1KYPbM0Swd0MJQ_oox0zTjYYCr57YDEy

With that document you will have all the information about the feed and you can further process it using other methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But on opening first link, I got 404 error like this. 

404. That’s an error.

The requested URL /feeds/videos.xml?playlist_id=ID was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

Comment: Right, and if you read the sentence right after that you will see me telling you to replace ID with the playlist ID.  I even gave you an example.

Comment: Thanks for  your comment. It works, but it only feeds 15 videos. I have over 300 videos in a playlist. Have you checked on this?

Comment: Ack, sorry didn't notice that.  I was using a smaller playlist for testing.  You certainly can get a full dump of videos in a playlist through the [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/), but I believe you must authenticate to use it, and you would have to write code.  With Google killing off the v2 version of the API a couple weeks back things like this have become far more difficult.